# How to Update one row data in existing excel sheet and dynamically update it's related column values

Tags: php, excel, laravel, symfony4

I have one predefined Excel sheet with formulas and data.
When I submit form I want to update one row data in that excel sheet and automatically update it's depending rows and columns values. I don't know other rows and columns formulas. Based on updating one row data automatically need to change other data in the Excel sheet.
Is it possible in php

Comment: Formulas (is this the "other data"?) that you want to change? are updated automatically (at least by default) in Excel.

Comment: Yes it is possible. But some more detail clarity , example data perhaps (output your expecting) and code/formulae youve tried would be useful to the person's helping you. By What formulas are in those cells. Where are they? Same sheet or other workbook? & When you say 'depending rows and columns' ,do you mean the r&c's that the row data is dependent UPON, or do you mean the r&c data that depends on the row data? Etc . Please edit your question so it's clearer to read and answer .

Comment: Data means, ex: we have one output template excel sheet contains 500 rows and 50 columns with predefined formulas. I am updating only 90-95 rows values in that sheet. Based on that other dependent rows values update automatically. We don't know that formulas.